# Spring AOP: intercepting multiple methods from multiple .class files in a jar

Tags: java, methods, jar, spring-aop

I have read Spring-AOP tutorials. What I figured out is, to intercept methods, we need to write a java file which will instantiate object of the class containing the methods. Then will call the methods in that class. At the same time there will be an xml configuration file with a bean of the class with methods. And, then we will have the class of interceptor method. The first java file I mentioned will have the main method and we will run this as a Java Application to start the interception. It is clear up till this.

Now, I have a jar containing multiple .class files. Each .class file contains a few methods. I need to intercept all these methods one by one during runtime. From my understanding as stated above, I need to instantiate objects of these classes in a java file. Then run that java file first. But, the jar I have is a web app and I don't know the sequence in which the .class files will be called. The files will be called according to the web user usage. In this scenario how can I create that java file with instantiated objects of the class files?

Please guide me here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP can work only with objects defined and instantiated from Spring context by Spring IoC container.

You can use JVM instrumentation API, it allows you to modify classes being loaded using some library like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/. See example here http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please explain it more? I didn't understand what do you mean by Spring Context here. Does it mean the bean that is declared in the Spring config xml?

Comment: Yes, exactly, though Spring can work without xml too

Comment: Does this mean, all the classes containing the methods should have a bean declaration in Spring? If yes, then how can I go by the flow of class calls in the webapp, but have then called from within Spring?

Comment: Yes, the class containg the mehtods you want to intercept and advise with Spring AOP should be Spring beans. As for webapps Spring can be embedded into a webapp thru web.xml

Comment: Can you please explain it in a bit more detail? How can web.xml help me with having multiple classes with methods, and the execution flow is as per the original webapp, but at the same time I am doing the AOP interception?

Comment: see spring docs http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-web-configuration